# Null reference exception in linq select statement

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I am getting a null reference exception from my bellow linq query. I have a table with an entityID(reference to another table to get translated text), but in some case i don't have proper translated text in my child table. This case i need to  take lookupName field text and assign to lookupName field.

```
 await _context.FormLookup.Where(x=>!(x.isDeleted))
                .Select(x => new LookupList() { 
                    lookupID = x.lookupID, 
                    TransilatedName = _context.TranslatedText.FirstOrDefault(z => z.entityID == x.entityID && z.languageId == language && !(z.isDeleted)).languageText, 
                    lookupName = x.lookupName, 
                    itemCount = x.lookupDetails.Count(),
                    parent = x.parentID
                }).ToListAsync();
```

I need to add a condition like

```
TransilatedName = _context.TranslatedText.FirstOrDefault(z => z.entityID == x.entityID && z.languageId == language && !(z.isDeleted)) != null ? TransilatedName = _context.TranslatedText.FirstOrDefault(z => z.entityID == x.entityID && z.languageId == language && !(z.isDeleted)).languageText : x.lookupName,
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Select property LanguateText before you use `FirstOrDefault`:

```
var query = dbContext.FormLookup
    .Where(x=>!(x.isDeleted))
    .Select(x => new LookupList()
    { 
        lookupID = x.lookupID, 
        TransilatedName = dbContext.TranslatedText
            .Where(translatedText => translatedText.entityID == x.entityID
                                  && translatedText.languageId == language 
                                  && !translatedText.isDeleted)
            .Select(translatedText => translatedText.languageText)
            .FirstOrDefault(), 
        ...
    });
```

Comment: thanks but again in some case languageText may not be available in db. so this case i need to assign lookupName filed value to TransilatedName  field

Comment: Sigh. If you had given your class descriptions, and used the proper pluralisations in your classes, the following would have been easier to describe. Your table TranslatedTexts (plural) is a table of zero or more rows. Each row contains one TranslatedText (singular). Every TranslatedText has a property LanguageText, which might be null. It might be that there are no rows left after your Where, but still: **every TranslatedText after the Where will have one property LanguageText**. Agree? So, from your possible empty sequence you can select this property. Result: a sequence of LanguageTexts.